# Running code when app is terminated. Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode12

I'm trying to run some code to refresh data and serve a local notification on iOS 14. I'm using Xcode 12 and all the help I find online is based on a structure having an appdelegate.swift swift file with several functions depending on the state of the app.

In Xcode 12 the appdelegate file isn't there anymore. How do I proceed, I don't know where to start. Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is probably that you set up the project to use `SwiftUI`. You need to create an AppDelegate object that implements `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        print("Your code here")
        return true
    }

    // Implement other methods that you require.

}
```

On your SwiftUI file, add this line to tell `iOS` who's gonna be the listener for the `AppDelegate`'s methods:

```
@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

You can then follow by checking [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh) on how to use background app modes.